# Prevent Search Engine from Accessing a particular database field

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

I want to hide some particular fields of my database (for ex: Age, Telephone number, Address) to be blocked for search engines..Is there any way to do so??

Working on phpMyAdmin..

Thanks

Comment: phpMyAdmin should *never* be public-facing. It should only live on your development machine. Use port forwarding to **tunnel** into your VPS over SSH if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search engines have no access to your database, whatsoever. Instead, they index content as provided by your web server. The pages (and the underlying script, code, etc.) are presented to a search engine indexer/crawler/bot similar to how a normal user would encounter the information.

You can use a [`robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file to instruct the search engine *not* to index given pages as a whole. There is not a way (to my knowledge) to simply hide certain pieces of information on a page from a search engine crawler.

Comment: +1 As an addition, serving different content to your visitors and search engines can get you penalized / blacklisted. Unless you exclude the whole detail pages from the search engines using `robots.txt`.

Comment: You can hide fields, but not advised. BMW were penalized years ago for "cloaking" content from search engines...

Comment: You can use a `robots.txt` file to instruct a _well-behaved_ search engine to ignore content. Sadly, not all bots obey the rules.